# Taylor Series - when to stop the accumulation or orders? - Numeric Analayze - rate of convergence

Tags: taylor-expansion, numerical-calculus, rate-of-convergence

Let us say we have the sequence:
$$\epsilon_{n+1}=\epsilon_n-\frac{1+\epsilon_n-e^{2\epsilon_n}}{1-2e^{2\epsilon_n}}$$
In order to find the rate of convergence, I have to do taylor series here.
Problem is, How do I know when do I stop?
I tried to take the first order of $e^{2\epsilon_n}$ and at the end I received:
$$\epsilon _{n+1}=\frac{4\epsilon_n\left(\epsilon_n-1\right)}{4\epsilon_n-1}$$
Which means my Rate of convergence should be 1 with $|A|=k$, for some k constant.
Although by the answer, the rate of convergence is 2.
To fix this, if I took the taylor series up to the second term, which means:
$$e^{2\epsilon_n}=1+2\epsilon_n+\frac{\left(2\epsilon_n\right)^2}{2!}$$

Then I will get the good answer, which rate of convergence of 2.

What is the reason of this? when do I know where to stop at taylor series so my rate of convergence rate will be accurate?

Comment: Perhaps you would want to double-check your first order computation.

Comment: Why? I did it twice, got the same result, believe me I would not ask otherwise, just writing here is longer then doing the solution for me :\ ( as a very basic latex user )

Comment: I will try this once again and update, 5min

Comment: Oh my god. I just noticed this, I saw my last two solution and now when I tried. I actually this about the exponent $1-2\epsilon_n$ instead of $1+2\epsilon_n$. Sorry for being an idiot... I dont know how I did not notice it... spent seriously like 30~40mins for the 2 solutions, checking what is wrong, and basically like 10~15min writing here.  I really feel like I am an idiot right now.. Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem :) It's that kind of thing that happens to all of us time to time.